# MVC 3 razor Storing user name of visitor via Windows Authentication using sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was trying to set a session in mvc to store the current user that visited the site. For example:

A user visits the site.
It gets recorded to the database as a login.
When the user closes his browser. The session is over.

With Windows Authentication I can get the user name with this
`User.Identity.Name`

In the _layout I was hoping I could do this:

```
@{
    var Data = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"];
    Data["UserSession"] = User.Identity.Name; 
}
```

But I cant. What is the proper syntax to set up a session variable and assing it a value of my user's identity.

Comment: It's not a good practice to set that information in your views. I'd do that wherever you're setting the User (like in an authorization attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["MySessionVariable"] = User.Identity.Name;
```

If thats not what you need then i need more clarification on what your asking

Comment: Is Session_Start in Global.asax.cs is the right place to write that piece of code?